# OSGI resolution error - missing system.bundle

Tags: osgi

I'm suddenly getting the following weird resolution error:

```
[ERROR] Resolution failed. Capabilities satisfying the following requirements could not be found:
[<<INITIAL>>]
  ? osgi.identity: (osgi.identity=javafx-osgi)
      ? [javafx-osgi version=8.0.2]
          ? osgi.wiring.host: (osgi.wiring.host=system.bundle)
```

It appears that the system bundle (Apache Felix framework) is no longer being found... Oddly, this error just popped up today. I havent worked on this project for a week. But the last commit ran without a problem.  If I revert to an earlier revision of the program, the problem remains...

We are using Java 1.8.0 161-b12; BND Tools 4.0.0 and Apache Felix Framework 1.8.

Our app.bndrun looks like this:

```
index: target/index.xml

-standalone: ${index}

-runrequires: osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service)', \
              osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=javafx-osgi)', \
              osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=com.foo.bar.command)',\
              osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=com.foo.bar.testservice)', \
              osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=com.foo.bar.main-screen)', \
              osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=com.foo.bar.verify-screen)', \
              osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=com.foo.bar.testclient)'

-runfw: org.apache.felix.framework;version='5.6.8'
-runee: JavaSE-1.8
-runbundles: \
    com.foo.bar.testservice;version='[0.0.1,0.0.2)',\
    org.apache.felix.scr;version='[2.1.0,2.1.1)',\
    org.osgi.service.log;version='[1.4.0,1.4.1)',\
    org.osgi.util.function;version='[1.1.0,1.1.1)',\
    org.osgi.util.promise;version='[1.1.0,1.1.1)',\
    org.osgi.util.pushstream;version='[1.0.0,1.0.1)',\
    com.foo.bar.testclient;version='[0.0.1,0.0.2)',\
    org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api;version='[1.10.1,1.10.2)',\
    org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service;version='[1.10.1,1.10.2)',\
    javafx-osgi;version='[8.0.2,8.0.3)',\
    com.foo.bar.launcher;version='[0.0.1,0.0.2)',\
    com.foo.bar.main-screen;version='[0.0.1,0.0.2)',\
    com.foo.bar.ui-main;version='[0.0.1,0.0.2)',\
    com.foo.bar.verify-screen;version='[0.0.1,0.0.2)',\
    org.apache.felix.configadmin;version='[1.9.2,1.9.3)',\
    com.foo.bar.launcher;version='[0.0.1,0.0.2)',\
    com.foo.bar.command;version='[0.0.1,0.0.2)'
-runproperties: felix.cm.dir="${user.home}\\Documents\\Prog731\\config"
```

This is a small demo program with very few dependencies. As far as I can determine, neither our code nor any the external dependencies have changed. But the problem is reproducible on different development machines...

What could cause a resolution error such as this?

**UPDATE:**
We are using the latest development snapshots of the bndtools 4.x from the https://bndtools.ci.cloudbees.com repository. Might this be it?

**UPDATE #2:**
As Requested, the MANIFEST of javafx-osgi-8.0.2.jar:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Export-Package: com.sun.javafx, com.sun.glass.ui, com.sun.javafx.anima
 tion, com.sun.javafx.applet, com.sun.javafx.application, com.sun.java
 fx.beans, com.sun.javafx.beans.event, com.sun.javafx.binding, com.sun
 .javafx.charts, com.sun.javafx.collections, com.sun.javafx.css, com.s
 un.javafx.css.converters, com.sun.javafx.css.parser, com.sun.javafx.c
 ursor, com.sun.javafx.effect, com.sun.javafx.embed, com.sun.javafx.ev
 ent, com.sun.javafx.font, com.sun.javafx.font.coretext, com.sun.javaf
 x.font.directwrite, com.sun.javafx.font.freetype, com.sun.javafx.font
 .t2k, com.sun.javafx.fxml, com.sun.javafx.fxml.builder, com.sun.javaf
 x.fxml.expression, com.sun.javafx.geom, com.sun.javafx.geom.transform
 , com.sun.javafx.geometry, com.sun.javafx.iio, com.sun.javafx.iio.bmp
 , com.sun.javafx.iio.common, com.sun.javafx.iio.gif, com.sun.javafx.i
 io.ios, com.sun.javafx.iio.jpeg, com.sun.javafx.iio.png, com.sun.java
 fx.image, com.sun.javafx.image.impl, com.sun.javafx.jmx, com.sun.java
 fx.logging, com.sun.javafx.media, com.sun.javafx.menu, com.sun.javafx
 .perf, com.sun.javafx.print, com.sun.javafx.property, com.sun.javafx.
 property.adapter, com.sun.javafx.robot, com.sun.javafx.robot.impl, co
 m.sun.javafx.runtime, com.sun.javafx.runtime.async, com.sun.javafx.ru
 ntime.eula, com.sun.javafx.scene, com.sun.javafx.scene.control, com.s
 un.javafx.scene.control.behavior, com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin, 
 com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.caspian, com.sun.javafx.scene.contr
 ol.skin.caspian.images, com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.modena, com
 .sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.resources, com.sun.javafx.scene.input,
  com.sun.javafx.scene.layout, com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.region, com
 .sun.javafx.scene.paint, com.sun.javafx.scene.shape, com.sun.javafx.s
 cene.text, com.sun.javafx.scene.transform, com.sun.javafx.scene.trave
 rsal, com.sun.javafx.scene.web, com.sun.javafx.scene.web.behavior, co
 m.sun.javafx.scene.web.skin, com.sun.javafx.sg, com.sun.javafx.sg.pri
 sm, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.web, com.sun.javafx.stage, com.sun.javafx
 .text, com.sun.javafx.tk, com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum, com.sun.javafx.u
 til, com.sun.javafx.webkit, com.sun.javafx.webkit.drt, com.sun.javafx
 .webkit.prism, com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.resources, com.sun.javafx.
 webkit.prism.theme, com.sun.javafx.webkit.theme, javafx, javafx.anima
 tion, javafx.application, javafx.beans, javafx.beans.binding, javafx.
 beans.property, javafx.beans.property.adapter, javafx.beans.value, ja
 vafx.collections, javafx.collections.transformation, javafx.concurren
 t, javafx.css, javafx.embed, javafx.embed.swing, javafx.event, javafx
 .fxml, javafx.geometry, javafx.print, javafx.scene, javafx.scene.canv
 as, javafx.scene.chart, javafx.scene.control, javafx.scene.control.ce
 ll, javafx.scene.effect, javafx.scene.image, javafx.scene.input, java
 fx.scene.layout, javafx.scene.media, javafx.scene.paint, javafx.scene
 .shape, javafx.scene.text, javafx.scene.transform, javafx.scene.web, 
 javafx.stage, javafx.util, javafx.util.converter, com.sun.deploy.uito
 olkit.impl.fx
Fragment-Host: system.bundle; extension:=framework
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: JavaFX 8 OSGi extension bundle
Bundle-License: The Apache License, Version 2.0
Bundle-SymbolicName: javafx-osgi
Bundle-Version: 8.0.2
```

**UPDATE #3:**
I think the javafx-osgi issue is not the real problem. I threw out all FX related stuff and ended up with an error saying "No OSGi framework has been added to the run path"?!

[image]

Comment: Are you certain that the Felix Framework JAR is available in the `index.xml`? Could you attach the content of the MANIFEST.MF for bundle `javafx-osgi`?

Comment: @NeilBartlett I've attached the MANIFEST. I also looked in the index.xml, but don't really know what to look for.

Comment: Thanks, the MANIFEST.MF, it looks fine (it's a bit worrying that you have all those exports with no version, but that's a separate discussion). I do need to see the index.xml. Since it is big, you might need to upload somewhere (Github Gist?).

Comment: @NeilBartlett The repo is not public. I uploaded the index contents to https://pastebin.com/Rzx4U336

Comment: Sorry for the delay replying. It looks like your repository does not contain the Felix Framework, `org.apache.felix.framework`. So your `-runfw` instruction is unmatched.

Comment: @NeilBartlett This is a very weird issue. After I had added the Felix framework to the pom.xml on friday, I could successfully build the project again in eclipse. However, maven (v3.5.4) installed in my PATH will hang trying to build... I've waited until I ran out of disk space :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the felix resolver:

- Insights from the Bndtools bugtracker: https://github.com/bndtools/bndtools/issues/1877
- Felix bugtracker: older issue with felix 5.4.0 and bndtools 3.4.0 [ResolverImpl infinite loop](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-5648)

The above felix ticket has been open for over a year and there doesn't seem a solid understanding (yet) what the root cause is.

For those who hit the same roadblock: We ended up switchting to eclipse equinox.